# Unable to execute my binary file due to mismatch in CFITSIO_SONAME value

Tags: c, gcc, runtime, astronomy, fits

I was trying to use the CFITSIO library in one of my projects. I have the library installed globally (inside /usr) which is working perfectly.

Additionally, in my project, in my “Include” folder I have another set of files from CFITSIO (including “fitsio.h”).

The project compiles successfully into a binary without any error. However, when I try to execute the binary, it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: Mismatch in the CFITSIO_SONAME value in the fitsio.h include file
that was used to build the CFITSIO library, and the value in the include file
that was used when compiling the application program:
   Version used to build the CFITSIO library   = 9
   Version included by the application program = 2

Fix this by recompiling and then relinking this application program 
with the CFITSIO library.
```

I assume that the compiler is taking the CFITSIO files from /usr directory as the CFITSIO_SONAME value is 9 in that file (I checked) and the CFITSIO_SONAME value is 2 in the fitsio.h file in the local project directory.

I have included “fitsio.h” with double quotes (“) instead of angular brackets (<>) so that the compiler looks in the local project directory first.

However, I am unable to achieve this. Is there anything I am missing here ? Any help would be appreciated ? Thanks !

Comment: Why are you using your own copy of the headers and not the ones that were installed with the library?  How did you install CFITSIO in the first place?

Comment: I am using a C application provided by my thesis advisor. Therefore, all the required dependencies are already present in the directory. I installed CFITSIO globally using these instructions: https://guaix.fis.ucm.es/~ncl/howto/howto-cfitsio